# Use JSON with jQuery and dataset(how to loop the values)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dataset

I want to use a HTML5 dataset to get values in JSON format and use them. The examples below are in JSON format(path and duration) or just the path.

My question is how can you get and loop the values?

HTML(JSON)

```
<div id="widget" data-load="{"ajax/ajax1.php" : 50, "ajax/-ajax2.php" : 20}">
```

OR

HTML(basic)

```
<div id="widget" data-load="ajax/ajax1.php">
```

Comment: For sure not with double quotes around double quotes

Comment: hint:  elm.dataset={a:1,b:2} seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this (second example)

```
$(function() {
  var $widget=$("#widget");
  $.get($widget.data("load"),function(data) {
    $.each(data.something,function(key, value) {
      $widget.append(value);
  });
});
```